# Count Repeated number from randomly generated integer

Tags: c++, random

This code generate 100 random number between 1 to 100.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
     srand(time(NULL));

     for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
     {
     cout <<  rand() % 100 + 1 << "\t";  //number between 1 and 100

if ((i+1) % 5 == 0)
            cout << endl;

     }


     return 0;
}
```

I want to **add a function** in this code so that it count how many times a number is repeated in the output. For example in this result-

```
56  96  75  53  67  
89  23  26  27  99  
30  29  2   63  27  
32  49  18  79  16  
56  31  95  46  82  
30  63  68  68  100 
7   23  95  81  75  
13  21  97  39  99  
48  68  28  49  83  
6   32  31  23  11  
98  30  93  93  76  
74  74  38  42  41  
37  48  16  84  81  
90  48  1   39  86  
52  86  6   79  86  
88  36  17  70  11  
27  19  40  71  63  
67  45  37  56  38  
29  45  85  44  80  
17  86  27  70  76
```

The number 86 repeated 3 times

The number 56 repeated 3 times

The number 89 repeated 1 times ... etc.

How can I do it?

Comment: Yes, I got some solution on "Counting repeated number specified in an array". But that is not what I want.

Comment: Make a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram)

Comment: Or you can sort the array, walk through it and count consecutive duplicates. Another option is inserting in `std::map<int, int>` where the key are your random numbers and the value is number of occurences.

Comment: @jrok : Could you please elaborate how to do that? (I am sorry if it seems like a silly question).

Comment: @aries0152 count on the fly: `int freq[101] = {0}; // default values are zero freq=occurrence` in loop `for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){ num = rand() % 100 + 1;  freq[num]++; }`

Comment: @aries0152 Additionally, don't use your formula to generate random numbers in a range instead do like: [`M + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (N - M + 1) + 1)`](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html) for range `[M, N]`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan : Thank you, That is the hint I was looking for. +1 on you comment.

Comment: @aries0152 your welcome, consider the **Link** I given in second comment, that is much important to understand. btw how is in the picute Einstein?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan : I have checked the link, that was a nice piece of information. And you are right, it is the picture of Einstein, I have found it on Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that... 
NB: I tried to take into account some comment

```
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <map>
    #include <algorithm>



    int main()
    {
         srand(time(NULL));
         std::map<int,int> histo;
         int N = 1 , M = 100;

         for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
         {
              int rnd = M + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (N - M + 1) + 1);

              histo[rnd] += 1;

              std::cout << rnd << std::endl;
              if ((i+1) % 5 == 0)
                  std::cout << std::endl;

         }

         for(auto var = begin(histo) ; var != end(histo) ; ++var)
         {
             std::cout << var->first << " have  " << var->second << " occurence " << std::endl;
         }

         return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I am still newbie when it comes to the c++11. But your code is clear. Thanks for helping. Accepted and voted up.

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of what the comments have said, a very quick and dirty way would be simply define a 100 element array of integers (initialized to 0), use the random number itself as the index and increment the array element by 1 with every random number generated.

Comment: dirty? I think it's a clean solution.